# MemcachePool not found

Tags: php, memcached

I am trying to use MemcachePool in my code, it reports the following error in PhP:

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MemcachePool' not found in test.php

Here is the code snippet:

```
$this->mMemcached = new MemcachePool();
$this->mMemcached->addServer(...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i never heard of `MemcachePool` - maybe you just wanted to use [Memcache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) (thats where [addServer()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.addserver.php) can be found)? in that case, just change your code to:

```
$this->mMemcached = new Memcache();
$this->mMemcached->addServer(...);
```

if this isn't what you're looking for, `MemcachePool` has to be a third party extension that hasn't been installed or a custom (wrapper)-class wich you forgot to include.

Comment: MemcachePool seems to be introduced in memcached-3.0.5. I installed it and it seems to be working fine now.